# npm installs many dependencies

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm, package

I bought an HTML template recently, which contains many plugins placed inside a `bower_components` directory and a `package.js` file inside. I wanted to install another package I liked, but decided to use `npm` for this purpose.

When I typed:

`npc install pnotify`

the `node_modules` directory was created and contained about 900 directories with other packages.

What are those? Why did they get installed along with my package? I did some research and it turned out that those were needed, but do I really need to deliver my template in production with hundreds of unnecessary packages?

Comment: Of course you need, almost every installed package uses a few other package, and each of them use other package, etc.

Comment: @alexmac I don't understand that, since my template is working fine without them so I don't really get the point of it.

Comment: `pnotify` uses 4 packages: https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/blob/master/package.json#L18.

Comment: Still 4 and not 900. They weigh over 40 mb, so I still don't get the point of delivering over 40mb of unnecessary data in production...

Comment: Yes 4, but each of them has own dependencies. Run `npm ls` in your project root, it will show you the the of installed packages.

Comment: I added a bounty for this seeking canonical answer just to clear the things up. What is the point of delivering hundreds of packages weighing hundreds of MB for a few kB project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very good question. There are a few things I want to point out.

**The V8 engine, Node Modules (dependencies)  and "requiring" them:**

Node.js is built on V8 engine, which is written in C++. This means that Node.js' dependencies are fundamentally written in C++.

Now when you require a dependency, you really require code/functions from a C++ program or js library, because that's how new libraries/dependencies are made.

**Libraries have *so* many functions that you will *not* use**

For example, take a look at the  [express-validator module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator), which contains so many functions. When you require the module, do you use all the functions it provides? The answer is **no**. People most often require packages like this just to use one single benefit of it, although all of the functions end up getting downloaded, which takes up unnecessary space.

**Think of the node dependencies that are made from other node dependencies as Interpreted Languages**

For example, JavaScript is written in C/C++, whose functions and compilers are in turn originally written in assembly. Think of it like a tree. You create new branches each time for more convenient usage and, most importantly, to *save time* . It makes things *faster*. Similarly, when people create new dependencies, they use/require ones that already exist, instead of rewriting a whole C++ program or js script, because that makes everything easier.

**Problem arises when requiring other NPMs for creating a new one**

When the authors of the dependencies require other dependencies from here and there just to use a few (small amount) benefits from them, they end up downloading them all, (*which they don't really care about because they mostly **do not** worry about the size or they'd rather do this than explicitly writing a new dependency or a C++ addon*) and this takes extra space. For example you can see the dependencies that the `express-validator` module uses by accessing [this link.](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/blob/master/package.json)

So, when you have big projects that use lots of dependencies you end up taking so much space for them.

**Ways to solve this**

**Number 1**

This requires some expert people on Node.js. To reduce the amount of the downloaded packages, a professional Node.js developer could go to the directories that modules are saved in, open the javascript files, take a look at their source code, and delete the functions that they will not use without changing the structure of the package.

**Number 2 (Most likely not worth your time)**

You could also create *your own* personal dependencies that are written in C++, or more preferably js, which would literally take up the least space possible, depending on the programmer, but would take/waste the most time, in order to reduce size instead of doing work. (**Note:** Most dependencies are written in js.)

**Number 3 (Common)**

Instead of Using option number 2, you could implement [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/).

**Conclusion & Note**

So, basically, there is no running away from downloading all the node packages, but you could use solution number 1 if you believe you can do it, which also has the possibility of screwing up the whole intention of a dependency. (So make it personal and use it for specific purposes.) Or just make use of a module like WebPack.

Also, ask this question to yourself: Do those packages really cause you a problem?

Comment: I think OP talk about JavaScript dependencies, not C++ addons. And solution number 1 is not a good idea either as it break down the whole philosophy of package management. Some interesting readding: [pro](http://codetunnel.io/why-i-think-micro-packages-are-a-good-thing/) & [con](http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/).

Comment: I wanted to explain everything in detail, solution number 1 is possible, but not a good idea, you're right. Just wanted to show complex/good stuff.  @TGrif

Comment: Nice answer. However, I still don't really get why npm is doing that. This is not simplifing things. As an example you can take Python and it's packages which are being installed through `pip` or `easy_install`. When you need a certain package you type `pip install package` and you have just that, this package might have a dependencies hundreds of others packages but it's up to you to deliver them or you will be prompt about missing package when you run the script. Same could be done for Javascript (and make a console prompt when missing something).

Comment: Another problem is when you use a PHP framework with some theme system with assets. Basically all assets should be stored in one directory `/assets/js`. Now when it comes to using npm, this is a problem. You need a 'special' path for each file installed through npm (I mean the path you include in your HTML like `<script src=".."></script>`). This is just another downside of it. Maybe it can be compiled/moved somehow but I have no idea about that.

Comment: for your last question, depending on the file syntax it might take a little work but you can `export` all the variables into one file and link that one to your html, and for the first one, yeah it's just a down side of it. @DonaldDuck

Comment: @turmuka I heard that this is done better with bower package manager (flat package tree). No idea, because I bought the template with npm used already. I have read somewhere that it's possible with NPM to bundle few scripts into one as well - any knowledge about that?

Comment: you are talking about webpack @DonaldDuck https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYo7YymudpE&t=49s check this video to get an idea

Comment: As the express-validator maintainer, I would like to say that **no**, it doesn't contain many functions. Also, it doesn't matter if a dependency has 900 functions, 2 MB, 30 dependencies, etc. Everything boils down to how many lines of code the end users have to write in order to achieve what they want. Finally, using a famous quote... _"premature optimization is the root of all evil"_ - KNUTH, Donald.

Comment: you are right, maybe that example wasn't *too* good, I have to say @gustavohenke but the op is not asking for efficiency, as I am showing examples of node module structures. MB and dependencies might not matter for you, nor does it for me, but that was the recent question and discussion.

Comment: having too many dependencies do matter at some cases of course, as it was asked as a question. Not only for node projects but in every project, you never wanna have extra files. they might slow down the app depending on syntax or take extra space. well, that still depends on you if they're not too many. You'd go for the one which does the best with the least size.

Comment: You're also right, size does matter at some point. *No one* likes to wait (end users loading the app, developers downloading lots of deps). I only criticised your question for not spreading the right thing.

Comment: There is an option 3, if the size is a problem on re-distribution..  Node.Js is javascript, as such it can also be packaged with something like webpack.  Webpack is not often used for node.js, but it works with it.  And if possible tree-shaking etc, can then be applied substantially reducing your dist size.

Comment: it's still not ***incorrect***, it's only that my example and explanation might be a little complex, the more functions you have equals to bigger size @gustavohenke

Comment: @turmuka While it is possible to write a C++ addon for node and make it available to your JS code, typical dependencies are written in JS, not in C++. The JS is compiled by a JIT compiler into bytecode at runtime and never converted to anything vaguely resembling C++. The solution if you have too many node dependencies is to write your own javascript to replace the code you depend on, _not_ to try and write a C++ addon just to replace a few functions.

Comment: Thanks for helping, and that is exactly what I said, where does that javascript code come from in a typical node module? there are things you can do in Node.JS and not in plain javascript. They all come from C++, and they are used by javascript functions. So you are right, you do write your own javascript to reduce the size, and those modules come from C++ @skylize

Comment: @turmuka. Yes, node has built-in functionality that is written in C++. These are exposed to your JS through an API, similar to using things `getElementById()` in the browser is calling to a C++ process. But a surprising amount of "core node.js" is written in javascript, for instance the `http` module is almost entirely javascript. The javascript in a typical node module comes from a coder like you or me spending some time to write up a library and publishing it to the [`npm` registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish)

Comment: :) i have to agree, at the end, they all come from C++ and that's what I meant in my answer. I wanted to make everything in detail. http written in Javascript -> Javascript func written in -> C++. So you're using a javascript function to make everything faster while writing the http library right? and still, it's most fundamental structure is still c++, that proves my solution 2. but is that a good option? depends on you and who you work with and most of the cases no it is not, because we already have enough javascript as you mentioned. :) @skylize

Comment: @turmuka. No. Overal your post was excellent, but I think you explained this part fundamentally incorrectly. The javascript uses tools provided to it by the pre-compiled C++, but the javascript itself is just javascript. It's fundamental structure is javascript. It's fundamental behavior is javascript. It goes through a compiler at run time and gets converted directly to byte code. The compiler happens to be written in C++, but it could just as easily be written in any other language and still compile the javascript to bytecode the same way.

Comment: thank you :), yes but for the node modules that come directly from c++, the OP could write smaller c++ program to reduce the size is all I was after @skylize

Comment: i like your explanation, the bytecodes are interesting in the run time(JIT). @skylize

Comment: @turmuka. Yes. If OP has dependencies that use C++ addons, then he could replace them with his own C++ addon. But OP made no mention of this and it is most likely is not the issue. More likely all or most of the dependencies in OP's `node_modules` folder are just little tiny snippets javascript, and if looking to replace them with own code, JS would be the way to go.

Comment: Any turing complete language is by definition capable of simulating any other, and thus disproving your theory that "Javascript is written in C/C++ languages" (what does *that* mean?), and that *"C/C++ languages"* are "written in Assembly". That machine code object you're calling V8 is not C or C++ code; the C or C++ code is source code. The machine code is simulating the *Javascript* turing machine, brought to you by your compiler and your computer simulating a *machine code* turing machine. *"Interpreted Languages"*? SICP covers interpreters and compilers, but doesn't bind them to languages.

Comment: I understand, yeah I fundamentally explained it wrong there. I should have specified it with *in case you have c++ addons* and wrote it in another part. Other than that javascript is just a binary code and the op could change modules source by changing JS source code. @Sebivor

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no point to add about 900 packages dependencies in your project just because you want to add some template. But it is up to you!

The heavyness of a template is not challenging the node.js ecosystem nor his main package system npm.

It is a fact that javascript community tend to make smallest possible module to be responsible for one task, and just one.
It is not a bad thing I guess. But it could result of a situation where you have a lot of dependencies in your project.

Nowadays hard drive memory is cheap and nobody cares any more about making efficient/small apps.

As always, it's only a matter of choice.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the point of delivering hundreds of packages weighing hundreds of MB for a few kB project.

There isn't..

If you intend to provide it to other developers, just gitignore (or remove from shared package) `node_modules` or `bower_components` directories. Developers simply install dependencies again as required ;)

If it is something as simple as an HTML templates or similar stuff, node would most likely be there just for making your life as a developer easier providing live reload, compiling/transpiling typescript/babel/SCSS/SASS/LESS/Coffee... ( list goes on ;P ) etc.

And in that case dependencies would most likely only be dev_dependencies and won't be required at all in production environment ;)

Also many packages come with separate production and dev dependencies, So you just need to install production dependencies...

```
npm install --only=prod
```

If your project does need many projects in production, and you really really wanna avoid that stuff, just spend some time and include css/js files your your project needs(this can be a laborious task).

---

Update

**Production vs default install**

Most projects have different dev and production dependencies,

Dev dependencies may include stuff like SASS, typescript etc. compilers, uglifiers (minification), maybe stuff like live reload etc.

Where as production version will not have those things reducing the size `node_modules` directory.

** No `node_modules`**

In some html template kind of projects, you may not need any `node_modules` in production, so you skip doing an `npm install`.

**No access to `node_modules`**

Or in some cases, when server that serves exists in node_modules itself, access to it may be blocked (coz there is no need to access these from frontend).

Comment: What does it change when I use dev dependencies instead default ones? Do each have any advantage of another? I think in both cases I will end with the same results - folder being created and flooded with tons of libs. On the other hand, when looking at some websites claiming to use npm, they don't have package.json on their page - thats the thing. Some simply either block access to it or... remove it for production? This is actually a good question, is it reasonable blocking access to it? I think I just care too much ;-)

Comment: @DonaldDuck While in root directory of `packageA`, if you type `npm install`,then all of both `dependencies` and `devDependencies` are installed from `package.json` of `packageA`. If you type `npm install -s packageB`, then only regular `dependencies` of `packageB` will be installed for use by `packageA`. Use `devDependencies` for things required to _build_ the module and `dependencies` for things required to _use_ the module.

Answer (score 0):

> What are those? Why did they get installed along with my package?

Dependencies exists to facilitate code reuse through modularity.

> ... do I need to deliver my template in production with hundreds of unnecessary packages?

One shouldn't be so quick to dismiss this modularity. If you inline your `require`s and eliminate dead code, you'll lose the benefit of maintenance patches for the dependencies automatically being applied to your code. You should see this as a form of *compilation*, because... well... *it is compilation*.

Nonetheless, if you're licensed to redistribute all of your dependencies in this *compiled* form, you'll be happy to learn those optimisations are performed by a compiler which compile Javascript to Javascript. [The Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), as the first example I stumbled across, appears to perform [advanced compilation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3), which means you get *dead code removal* and *function inlining*... That seems promising!

Answer (score 0):

This does however have another side effect when you are required to justify the licensing of all npm modules..so when you have hundreds of npm modules due to dependencies this effort also becomes a more cumbersome task

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but I happened to come across very similar situation just as `RA` pointed out.

I tried to work with node.js framework using `vscode` and the moment when I tried to install start npm using `npm init -y`, it generated so many different dependencies. In my case, it was `vscode` extension `ESlint` that I added to prior to running `npm init -y`

- Uninstalling `ESlint`
- Restarted `vscode` to apply that uninstallation
- removed previously generated `package.json` and `node-modules` folder
- do `npm init -y` again

This solved my problem of starting out with so many dependencies.